# Selecting substring from base64 converted file in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have file already converted into base64 format

```
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
```

Now I want to select every 30 char follow by dot and create new line in powershell like example below

```
c3VkbyBkb2NrZXIgcnVuIC1kIFwgwq.
DCoC0tbmFtZSBibG94Lm5vYSBcIMKg.
wqAtLW5ldHdvcms9aG9zdCBcIMKgwq.
AtdiAvdmFyL3J1bi9kb2NrZXIuc29j.
azovdmFyL3J1bi9kb2NrZXIuc29jay.
BcIMKgwqAtdiAvdmFyL2xpYi9pbmZv.
YmxveC9jZXJ0czovdmFyL2xpYi9pbm.
ZvYmxveC9jZXJ0cyBcIMKgwqAtdiAv.
ZXRjL29ucHJlbS5kLzovZXRjL29ucH.
JlbS5kLyBcIMKgwqBpbmZvYmxveGN0.
by9vbnByZW0uYWdlbnQ6djQuMS41IF.
wgwqDCoC0tam9pbnRva2VuPWh4YlFo.
YXcxa2M2MFpKV3JYdzNOU1pUdVExMD.
dZSFU2aGpaVUxfQngwWXJu.
```

In bash it can be done using awk like below

```
base64 filename | awk '{for(i=1;i<length;i+=100) print substr($0,i,100) "."}'
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to print to the console or continue in pipeline? Is an array of strings fine, or do you need newline characters?

Comment: Please post your attempt at implementing it in PowerShell and explain what issues you're having with your attempted implementation.

Comment: Wants to continue in pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Base64 -Replace '(.{30})', "`$1.`r`n"
```

Comment: Nice and succinct. I suggest to replace `\`r\`n` by  `[Environment]::NewLine` to make this platform-independent. Also you could remove the group and use `$0` to replace with the whole match: `$Base64 -Replace '.{30}', ('$0.' + [Environment]::NewLine)`.